# Eclipse fails compiling apk

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

Im new to android.
I have been writing my first app, I testing it about 2 weeks now.
Everything is went good, when today my apk doesnt want to be installed on my Phone.
So the followings happen:
I use eclipse.
I export the app with the right way:
Android Tools -> Export Signed Application -> bablabla I got a key and everything so..

The Emulator runs it perfectly, but when I try to install it on my phone, its icon not showing as an android application, its like 3 blank pages, so it shows as an "unknow" file format, and when i try to install, error message appears: "No applications can perform this action"

It seems like Eclipse didnt build my project as an .apk file.

Can somebody helps me?
What changed? Before this I could ran my apks on my Phone.
(Samsung Galaxy S, but I dont think its really matter, I guess it will be an Eclipse thingee)

Comment: Try uninstalling all previous versions of the app from your phone and start from fresh.  Sometimes this helps

Comment: I found something new...
"Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"
So this thing pushes me to an another question thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this documentation: [debbuging android app on device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

It looks rather like problem with manifest file, but I think You can run Your app by description from the link.